# How do I join views using std::ranges

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

How do I join two views using std::ranges?
In ranges-v3 the views are joined with views::concat(), and I cannot figure out how to do that with std::ranges.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <ranges>
using namespace std;
using namespace views;

void snake_to_camel() {   
    auto transform = views::transform;
    auto const s = string{"feel_the_force"};
    auto words = s | split('_');                        // [[f,e,e,l],[t,h,e],[f,o,r,c,e]]
    auto words_cap = words | transform([](auto word){
        auto transform = views::transform;
        auto head = word | take(1) 
                         | transform([](unsigned char c){return toupper(c);}); // e.g. [F]
        auto tail = word | drop(1);                     // e.g. [e.e.l]
        return tail;
        //return concat( head, tail );                  // e.g. [F,e,e,l] // join( head, tail ) will not work here.
    });                                                 // [[F,e,e,l],[T,h,e],[F,o,r,c,e]]
    auto s_camelcase = words_cap | join;                // [F.e.e.l.T.h.e.F.o.r.c.e]
    string res;
    for(auto c : s_camelcase)
        res.push_back(c);
    cout << res;
}

int main() {
    snake_to_camel();
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Tricky. Unfortunately, something like `std::array parts{head, tail}; return join(parts);` doesn't work. I'm afraid you'd have to reimplement ranges-v3's `views::concat()` yourself, or of course just use ranges-v3.

Answer (score 3):

C++20 cannot do this.

But benefiting from [P2328](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2328r1.html) and [P2210](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2210r2.html), in C++23, we can do this in another way, that is, transform the split [`subrange`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/subrange) into a `string`, modify and return it, and finally `join`:

```
void snake_to_camel() {   
    auto transform = views::transform;
    auto const s = string{"feel_the_force"};
    auto words = s | split('_');                        // [[f,e,e,l],[t,h,e],[f,o,r,c,e]]
    auto words_cap = words | transform([](auto r) { 
                               std::string word(r);
                               word.front() = toupper(word.front());
                               return word;
                             });                        // [[F,e,e,l],[T,h,e],[F,o,r,c,e]]
    auto s_camelcase = words_cap | join;                // [F.e.e.l.T.h.e.F.o.r.c.e]
    string res;
    for(auto c : s_camelcase)
        res.push_back(c);
    cout << res;
}
```

[Demo.](https://godbolt.org/z/MavTe1en6)

Comment: Both of those are defects against C++20, so what you wrote here should be valid C++20.

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out. But how should I describe it properly? "Since C++20", "the anaphase of C++20"...

Comment: That's a good question... since C++21? :-) Don't actually know.

Comment: Interesting, but the "snake_to_camel" is only illustration. I was hoping for as "concat" that allows me to concatenate two different views.

Comment: Just use range-v3, C++20 has no such thing.

Comment: @Generic If you want to ask a question about concatenation different views, I suggest you ask _that_ question (it is not clear to me from your question that this is what you wanted).